# Strange behaviour when creating python attributes in cython cdef class

Tags: cython, cythonize

We have given Cython code:

```
cdef extern from "C_File_A.h":
    cdef struct C_Obj_A:
        pass

cdef extern from "C_File_B.h":
    cdef struct C_Obj_B:
        pass

cdef class pC_Obj_A:
    cdef const C_Obj_A * _c_self

cdef class pC_Obj_B:
    cdef const C_Obj_B * _c_self

cdef class pC_Obj_C:
    cdef const C_Obj_A * _c_a
    cdef const C_Obj_B * _c_b


cdef class Obj_A_Wrap(pC_Obj_A):
    def __init__(self, pC_Obj_C obj_c):
        self._c_self = obj_c._c_a


cdef class Obj_B_Wrap(pC_Obj_B):
    def __init__(self, pC_Obj_C obj_c):
        self._c_self = obj_c._c_b


cdef class Stack:
    cdef public pC_Obj_A obj_a
    cdef public pC_Obj_B obj_b

    def __init__(self, pC_Obj_C obj_c):
        # Working
        self.obj_a = Obj_A_Wrap(obj_c)
        self.obj_b = Obj_B_Wrap(obj_c)

        # Working
        self.obj_a._c_self = obj_c._c_a
        self.obj_b = Obj_B_Wrap(obj_c)

        # Working
        self.obj_a = Obj_A_Wrap(obj_c)
        self.obj_b._c_self = obj_c._c_b

        # Not working
        self.obj_a._c_self = obj_c._c_a
        self.obj_b._c_self = obj_c._c_b
```

I need a python object `Stack` with attrubutes accessible from Python, so I have added to Stack class `cdef public pC_Obj_A obj_a` and `cdef public pC_Obj_B obj_b`.These objects are wrappers to the C struct pointers.

When I initialize these objects with intermediary wrappers i.e. `Obj_A_Wrap` everything is fine.

When I initialize one of these objects directly i.e. `self.obj_a._c_self = obj_c._c_a` also everything is fine.

When both `obj_a` and `obj_b` are initialized directly (`# Not Working` part of code) I have got strange behaviour of my C library that inlcude `C_File_A` and `C_File_B` and respectively the C structs definitions. The behaviour is similar to memory corruption, or overwriting some parts of the memory that should not be.

I have no idea why the direct initialization causes this strange behaviour. Maybe you know?

Comment: Try adding the line `print(self.obj_a, self.obj_b)` at the start of `__init__` - it might give you a clue what's going wrong. And bear in mind that some of what you label as "working" may just be "not crashing in an obvious way".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution of my problem. When I was trying to solve this problem I have printed only `_c_self` attribute of the given object to check that the pointer was properly assigned and it was but when I printed entire object it turned out that python object is `None` instead of proper object declared as attribute.

```
print(self.obj_a, self.obj_b) # 66f000c0 66f000c0
print(f'{<int>self.obj_a._c_self:x} {<int>self.obj_b._c_self:x}') # None None
```

The solution is to add `Create` function to cdef class:

```
cdef class pC_Obj_A:
    cdef const C_Obj_A * _c_self

    @staticmethod
    cdef Create(C_Obj_A * ptr):
        cdef pC_Obj_A result = pC_Obj_A()
        result._c_self = ptr
        return result
```

And use it like this:

```
cdef class Stack:
    cdef public pC_Obj_A obj_a
    cdef public pC_Obj_B obj_b

    def __init__(self, pC_Obj_C obj_c):
        self.obj_a = pC_Obj_A.Create(obj_c._c_a)
        self.obj_b = pC_Obj_B.Create(obj_c._c_b)
```

Then printout is:

```
print(self.obj_a, self.obj_b) # <pC_Obj_A object at 0x029FF610> <pC_Obj_B object at 0x029FF620>
print(f'{<int>self.obj_a._c_self:x} {<int>self.obj_b._c_self:x}') # 2134b9c 2134c08
```

And everything works great!